# ls and find give "invalid argument" when passing no argument

Tags: files, filesystem, ntfs, ls

I have an external hard drive, formatted with NTFS. On it I have one folder with about 100,000 files, totalling about 140GB (excluding overhead).

I'm finding that I can no longer list the files in the folder.

```
$ pwd
/media/matthew/nemweb/AppliedEconometrics/data/01-A-raw
$ ls
ls: reading directory '.': Invalid argument
$ ls $(pwd)
ls: reading directory '/media/matthew/nemweb/AppliedEconometrics/data/01-A-raw': Invalid argument
$ ls .
ls: reading directory '.': Invalid argument
$ find ./
./
find: './': Invalid argument
$ find $(pwd)
/media/matthew/nemweb/AppliedEconometrics/data/01-A-raw
find: '/media/matthew/nemweb/AppliedEconometrics/data/01-A-raw': Invalid argument
$ python3 -c "import os; os.listdir('.')"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '.'
```

I know that NTFS isn't great for one folder with this many files. My overall objective is to move the files to another drive, reformat the first drive as ext4, and then move the files back.

Whilst trying to copy the files across, my computer froze. After forcefully powering off and restarting, I had to use Ubuntu's disk repair feature before I could mount the drive. This behavior only started after that forceful reboot. (I suspect it's an filesystem corruption issue caused by lack of journaling?) I can still access other folders on this drive.

Why does `ls` give an error about bad arguments for this folder? If the filesystem is corrupt for that particular folder, I would not expect the error message to say the argument I provided is invalid.

Comment: Don't know what this has to do with Ubuntu, ...anyway, usually the advice is to get a Windows machine to repair ntfs file systems.